# windows network settings translated to ubuntu

Tags: networking, server

I was reading this post on entering a static IP.

It says to change these settings:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

What is the Windows equivalent to network and broadcast. I'm new to Ubuntu but I'm familiar with Windows.

Also, where do I put the dns server ips at? I have two ips for dns.

Thanks for the help!

** EDIT **

I found the dns server changes here:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/setup-static-dns-servers-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows 'Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)' dialog there is no direct equivalent of the network and broadcast fields because they can be inferred from the other fields - for example the broadcast address can be obtained by performing a bitwise OR of the bit complement of the subnet mask and the IP address - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

If you are running a desktop version of Ubuntu (using network-manager) then neither /etc/network/interfaces nor directly editing dhclient.conf are the recommended ways to modify IPv4 or DNS settings - instead, edit the connection via the nm-applet or nm-connection-editor. For example, you can specify a static configuration by setting the method to 'Manual' in the IPv4 settings tab and filling in the details in the boxes provided.

If you are using Ubuntu server (without network-manager) then the recommended way to specify DNS servers is to append them to the interface stanza in /etc/network/interfaces, e.g.

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your settings for a static ip on interfaces file:

`sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`

Then restart your networking:

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

If you want more info check out this [site](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/).

Comment: I appreciate the post but that really doesn't tell me what network and broadcast are...